# ping fails with MTU >= 298

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, mtu

For context, my original problem is that my ssh connection to my servers hangs at `expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY` when i connect to them via VPN (in this case, an OpenVPN running in pfsense).

The Internet indicates that may be linked to MTU issues.

While trying to debug this, this happened:

```
ping -s 297 -M do $HOST
```

works fine, but

```
ping -s 298 -M do $HOST
```

just hangs.

The MTU is set to 1500 on both my machine, the host, and the pfsense interface (although the interface is disabled in pfsense's UI, i'm not sure if it's supposed to be that way).

Why is that happening? Is something blocking packets too large? Where could i even dig for more clues?

`mtr $HOST` indicates two hops: to the pfsense, then to the server itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you have set MTU on the hosts you control means nothing
as the packets between them — in theory — might fly through any media with any MTU.

To deal with this issue (besides the IP fragmentation mechanism),
the so-called ["Path MTU discovery"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) mechanism exists.

Note that it relies on the ICMP protocol to work properly.
Beside other things, it means that if you have tight firewall settings,
you must have something like

```
iptables -t nat -A $CHAIN -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

in your rules for your `INPUT` chain (and in the `FORWARD` chain if your
firewall also does SNAT for its clients).

> The "related" state means that when an ICMP packet of the type 3,
>   code 4 (destination unreachable / fragmentation required)
>   is received, the conntrack subsystem decides which connection
>   it *is related to* and then passes it further down the netfilter stack.
>   The state of such packet is "RELATED" as known to `iptables`¹
>   so if you have passing of such packets denied — as often happens when
>   people disable everything wholesale and then punch the minimal holes —
>   P-MTU discovery won't work properly.

Note also that even if you "unbreak" proper support for P-MTU on your sides,
it might still be broken somewhere in between.

In order to deal with it, there exists at least two knobs:

- [Clamping MSS to MTU](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html) in the IP stack.
- Limiting these things on the OpenVPN level by its `tun-mtu`,
  `tun-mtu-extra` and `mssfix` knobs.

Note that these settings does affect performance, so use as the last resort.

---

¹ Because while not a part of an IP exchange, it's clearly related to it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue:  pinging with size 297 worked, 298 did not.

Our client was configured to not use compression:

```
comp-lzo no
```

Changing it to use compression fixed the issue:

```
comp-lzo yes
```

I don't understand why this works, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue at home, with SSH connections hanging at (as I recall) the exact same place in the connection setup. For me, tweaking the local MTU setting helped reduce the problem somewhat, but to make the problem go away, **I had to turn on TCP MTU probing.** After doing so I didn't have any similar problems. Only allowing `RELATED` packets through iptables, as discussed in [kostix's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/881194/58408), didn't help.

For Linux, try

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1
```

The possible values are:

- `0` = disabled
- `1` = disabled by default, enabled when an ICMP black hole detected
- `2` = always enabled, use initial MSS of tcp_base_mss

Other OSes will be similar and different.

Note that this needs to be done on the client system, not the firewall (so not on the pfSense box) -- unless of course you are initiating your SSH connections from the firewall.